# Understanding the well-definedness proof of of Homotopy Lifting Property

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand the proof of Homotopy Lifitng Property given in Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, with the space $\widetilde{X}$ given below is a covering space of $X$.

> Given a map $F:Y\times I\to X$ and a map $\widetilde{F}:Y\times\{0\}\to\widetilde{X}$ lifting $F|_{Y\times\{0\}}$, then there is a unique map $\widetilde{F}:Y\times I\to\widetilde{X}$ lifting $F$ and restricting to the given $\widetilde{F}$ on $Y\times\{0\}$.

I'm able to prove all steps of the proof given for this property, except the part where the well-definedness of $\widetilde{F}$ is shown:

> The last step in the proof of (c) is to observe that since the $\widetilde{F}$'s constructed above on sets of the form $N\times I$ are unique when restricted to each segment $\{y\}\times I$, they must agree whenever two such sets $N\times I$ overlap. So we obtain a well-defined lift $\widetilde{F}$ on all of $Y\times I$.

Since this section of the proof likely use Pasting Lemma, my question here is how do we know that for each $y\in Y$, the associated neighborhood $N$ of it will overlap with another neighborhood $N'$ of $y'\in Y$? Couldn't we have a case where there exist a certain point $y_0$ where its associated neighborhood $N_0$ does not overlap with any other neighborhood associated with every other point on $Y$?

Comment: If they don't overlap, it doesn't matter.

Comment: But why it doesn't matter? I don't really understand the reasoning for this.

Comment: You should give more context. It seems that you consider a covering map, but you do not mention it.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, the property given in the book mentions $\widetilde{X}$ as covering space of $X$.

Comment: You should edit your question and include this information. People do not want to read comments to get all necessary information.